# position: fixed without using doctype in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How can we fix an element in HTML page without using `<!doctype>`?

Comment: `javascript` seems to be irrelevant here?

Comment: You should always use a doctype. I can't think of a single reason for not using one.

Comment: I don't see how a doctype is relevant either, unless it's about fixed-positioning stuff in quirks mode.

Comment: @Felix: Unless the question is how to do it with JavaScript. The fact is, we're left guessing...

Answer (score 1):

The key to an absolute or fixed position element is that it's parent element (let's say a container div) has to have `position:relative;`

For instance, if you have a container div that is 960px wide and centered on the page (like below):

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="AbsolutePositionedBox">
        // Box Content Goes Here
   </div>
</div>
```

the CSS to make it work correctly would be:

```
.container{
    width:960px; 
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
    #AbsolutePositionedBox{
        position: // absolute or fixed;
        top: // pixels from the RELATIVE parent (makes it easier to manage);
        LEFT OR RIGHT: // pixels from the RELATIVE parent;
    }
```

Just like TJ mentioned above, a fixed positioning stays put, even when the user scrolls, where as an absolute position is just positioned relative to an element and will scroll with the rest of the content.

Again, I would also **always** recommend using a doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Using [absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) (e.g., `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`) in the style ([examples](http://jsbin.com/odeze3)):

Absolute (scrolls with page):

```
<style type='text/css'>
#foo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
</style>
<div id='foo'>This is foo at 10x10</div>
```

Or if you prefer it inline:

```
<div style='position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;'>This is foo at 10x10</div>
```

Fixed (doesn't scroll):

```
<style type='text/css'>
#foo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10em;
    top: 2em;
}
</style>
<div id='foo'>This is foo at 10x10</div>
```

Or if you prefer it inline:

```
<div style='position: fixed; right: 10em; top: 2em;'>This is foo in the upper right</div>
```

Or if you want to do it via JavaScript (since your question was originallly tagged `javascript`):

```
var div = document.getElementById('foo');
div.style.position = "absolute"; // or "fixed" or whatever
div.style.left = "10px";
div.style.top = "10px";
```

---

Off-topic, but I would **always** recommend using a DOCTYPE. Without one, you run into different quirks in nearly every browser. While you still get browser differences with a DOCTYPE, they're fewer and a *bit* less insane...

Comment: That's absolute positioning — the div will still scroll with the page.

Comment: @BoltClock's Unicorn: Which may be what he/she wants, or may not (or do you think the questioner is so clear on this that he knows "fixed" is a CSS term?). As you were commenting I was adding links to CSS2.1 and mentioning fixed positioning.

Comment: OK, fair point. The downvote wasn't mine though, I'll +1 for the edit.